# Isareth the Awakener and championing

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Scenario:
[Isareth the Awakener](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIsareth%20the%20Awakener%5d) returns [Llanowar Elves](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLlanowar%20Elves%5d) to play.
I play [Changeling Hero](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChangeling%20Hero%5d) and exile Llanowar elves.
Changeling Hero is destroyed.

Does Llanowar elves get returned by the champion trigger?

Comment: agreed, it is a duplicate

Answer (score 4):

It would be returned; Isareth’s last sentence doesn’t do anything.

The replacement effect doesn’t actually apply, beause “instead of putting it anywhere else” means “instead of going to Exile”. Because it is going to Exile anyway; it doesn’t matter.